# Moodle 2.6 Call to undefined method core_renderer_maintenance

Tags: moodle, genesis

i got error of my moodle 2.6 and genesis theme (i have activate debug option ini php.ini)

> require_once(dirname(**FILE**) . '/lib/setup.php');
>   @error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); @ini_set('display_errors', '1');
>   $CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT); $CFG->debugdisplay = 1;
>   $CFG->debugusers = '2';

it's apprear when i login with admin privillage. (host/admin/index.php)

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   core_renderer_maintenance::socialicons() in
>   /var/www/../theme/genesis/layout/header.php on line 11

any one can help me, solution of this? thanks

Comment: The error message was obvious. There must be something missing. Try to var_dump(core_renderer_maintenance); and look for the class definition of core_renderer_maintenance

Comment: Ah I was going to have a look at the code for you but it looks like its a commercial theme - http://themeforest.net/item/genesis-moodle-theme/5457547

You need to contact their developers to fix it.

Comment: i have read in forum genesis, they say, genenis theme is for moodle 2.5 and not yet tested on moodle 2.6..